# linkTextAttributes doesn't work for font in Swift

Tags: swift, hyperlink, uitextview

I want to give specific fonts detected links in `UITextView`.

I tried the following code.

```
let linkAttributes: [String : Any] = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.humanBlue(), NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: UIFont.bbyFont(for: AppFont.medium, sizeClass: .m)]
infoLabelTextview.linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes
```

But it changes only `textcolor`. Can anyone please help me with this..

Comment: @Larme reported for off topic. That question is about NSAttributed string but this code should work for `textView.text` (not attributed text). Finally currently I have the same issue but in different swift version and your useless comments may cause this question to be closed

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov According the other answers and the behavior, `linkTextAttributes` doesn't read the Font value. So you have to do it yourself. And to do so with `textView.text`, you'll have to use `textView.attributedText` because `.text` can't have multiple font.

Comment: @Larme So the possible answer is iOSManiac uses `.text` but should use `attributedText`. And it worth to leave this topic as separate question.

Comment: For me it's the same issue and the same solution: It seems you have to do it yourself. Note that it's not flagged (did I just suggested it in comment, but not marked it as such?) and it would need 5 "flags" to mark it as duplicate (and still keep it visible btw).